# how do I find all .gitignore files in a project?

Tags: git

Hi I have a project where I've cloned third-party libs directly into it, and I realized I have a fair share of gitignore files and wanted to find them all for posterity's sake. How do I find them all ?

Comment: Can't you just use whatever your OS provides to find files called `.gitignore`?

Comment: @R0MANARMY: two people, same thought.

Comment: ha good call. brain-fart moment

Comment: @jdkealy feel free to delete the question and we'll all pretend nothing happened ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use your standard OS's methods for finding files; on unixoids, that'd be something like

```
 find -type f -name '.gitignore'
```

EDIT: also: if you're cloning repos into your own repo, you should consider using git-submodule.

Answer (score 3):

**Using `git ls-files`:**

```
git ls-files '*.gitignore'
```

- The wildcard is required for `ls-files` to search recursively.
- This actually finds any file ending with `.gitignore`

**Using `find`:**

```
find -type f -name .gitignore
```

- This also brings up `.gitignore` files that are not yet committed.

Answer (score 0):

To recursively find all your .gitignore files:
`cd /path/to/project/ && find ./ -type f -name "*.gitignore";`

To find and delete `cd /path/to/project/ && find ./ -type f -name "*.gitignore" -exec rm -f {} \;`

Comment: what's the rm -f all about

Comment: oh gotcha... to find and delete